# Why doesnt my Map display within Accordion Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have placed my Navigation within my accordion button/tab as i want the user to beable to just click on the tab and for them to see the navigation whenever it pleases them. The map and all the code to do with the map is fully functional as i get no errors when i test it on the console but for some reason it still does not display. I have also used the API Key. It will only work when i test it with the console also. Why is it not displaying the map when i click the tab?

This is the code i have for my map

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>London Tour Guide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <style>
        div.container { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 720px; height: 1300px;
            background-color: white; }

        div.content {
            width: 700px; height: 1200px;
            background-color: lightblue; padding: 5px; }

        h1.welcome {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center; text-shadow: 2px 2px Grey;
            transition: 4s;}

        h1.stpauls{font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1.welcome:hover{transform: rotateX(360deg); color:yellow; }

        p.medium {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #333;
        }

        p.small {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #333;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }



        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;

        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }


        .dropbtn1 {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        .dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }


        .dropdown1 {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }


        .dropdown1-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show{display:block;}

        button.accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        div.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
        }

        div.panel.show {
            display: block;
        }




    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class = "content">

    <div class = "header">
        <img src = "headerlondon.jpg" alt = "header"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Project.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Map.html">Maps </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="travel">Travel <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Bus.html">Bus</a>
                <a href="Taxi.html">Taxi</a>
                <a href="Tube.html">Tube</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="sightseeing">SightSeeing <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="LondonEye.html">London Eye</a>
                <a href="TowerofLondon.html">Tower of London</a>
                <a href="BigBen.html">Big Ben</a>
                <a href="StPaulsCathedral.html">St Pauls Cathedral</a>
                <a href="BuckinghamPalace.html">Buckingham Palace</a>
                <a href="WestMinister.html">WestMinister</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="Museums">Museums <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="BritishMuseum.html">British Museum</a>
                <a href="ScienceMuseum.html">Science Museum</a>
                <a href="NationalHistoryMuseum.html">National History Museumm</a>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

    <button class="accordion">Navigation</button>
    <div class="panel" style = "position: relative">
    <div id="map" style="width:50%;height:250px"></div>
        </div>



</div>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>

<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
        var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 10};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            icon: "poi.png"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E&callback=myMap"></script>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't display  or display a grey area ?

Comment: It is just displaying a grey area with the marker icon and no satellite view off the map

Comment: this is beacuse you tab is not visibile at startup  you should call the function for map when you press the tab .. so the maps is create when the tab is visible  ..

Comment: How do i go about doing that? Sorry im so very much frustrated with this part and it would go along way if someone could actually help me with it :)

Comment: You must call the myMap  when you click the tab..

Comment: But isnt that the purpose of map in the id below the panel? Where about in the code would i place the myMap, if you could post as an answer that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Usually maps require their container to be position:relative

Can you try adding position: relative to the panel class?

If that doesn't work, make sure your google maps app key is set from YOURKEY to whatever your key is.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOURKEY**&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: That didnt really help, should i place all my code in to give you a better idea? and yes i put my key to YOURKEY cause i dont want people having my api key

Comment: Can you post the site, or a fiddle of it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Maps require for the container to have a specific size and to be visible at the time its being loaded. It needs to know what size it should fit in

Comment: Well that didnt help atall, i change the size of the container for the panel and the map still did not appear